# Django form of CreateView not accepting submission after setting default value

Tags: python, django

My django form made using CreateView is refusing to get submitted because of the inital value I prepopulated it with ( and which is correct )

This is my model :

```
class Post(models.Model):
    #some code
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    #some more code
```

This is my view for the form :

```
class AddPostView(CreateView):
    model = Post
    form_class = PostForm
    template_name = 'add_post.html'

    def get_initial(self):
        initial = super(AddPostView, self).get_initial()
        #Setting the inital value of author in the form to the username of the logged in user 
        initial['author'] = self.request.user.username
        return initial
```

And this is the form being referred by the above view

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('x','y', 'author', 'z', 'm')
        widgets = {
            #some code
            'author': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','readonly':'readonly' }),
            #some more code

        }
```

Now , When I am trying to submit the form , I am getting the error

```
Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.
```

Why is this happening?d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form needs IDs for the `ForeignKey` fields, but you are providing names instead.

Change

```
initial['author'] = self.request.user.username
```

to

```
initial['author'] = self.request.user.pk
```

And leave the widget as a `ChoiceField`. Then it should work.

---

Or you need to modify the forms validation of the `author` field and do the `User` lookup by username manually; this could be done in the `clean_author()` method of the form.